# Animated 3d Arrow around an interpolating function

Tags: plotting, animation

I am trying to draw an arrow that originates from point {0,0,0} to the point of the curve. The arrow should rotate around the curve. I am attaching an animated figure as well so you know where the head of the arrow should be.

The last command is the one that I would like to get your comment to fix.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] (*Remove all global variables*)
alpha1 = 0.1;
gamma = 1/(1 + alpha1^2);
hexternal = {1, 0, 0};

hxexternal = hexternal[[1]];
hyexternal = hexternal[[2]];
hzexternal = hexternal[[3]];

equationM1 = {M1'[t] == 
    gamma*(alpha1*((Cos[M1[t]]*Cos[M2[t]])*
           hxexternal + (Cos[M1[t]]*Sin[M2[t]])*hyexternal - 
          Sin[M1[t]]*hzexternal) + ((-Sin[M2[t]])*
          hxexternal + (Cos[M2[t]])*hyexternal))};
equationM2 = {M2'[t] == 
    gamma*((-1/
          Sin[M1[t]])*((Cos[M1[t]]*Cos[M2[t]])*
           hxexternal + (Cos[M1[t]]*Sin[M2[t]])*hyexternal - 
          Sin[M1[t]]*hzexternal) + (alpha1/
          Sin[M1[t]])*((-Sin[M2[t]])*hxexternal + (Cos[M2[t]])*
           hyexternal))};

initial1 = {M1[0] == Pi/2 + 0.01};
initial2 = {M2[0] == Pi + 0.01};

eqns = Join[equationM1, equationM2, initial1, initial2];

sol1 = NDSolve[eqns, {M1[t], M2[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, 
   StartingStepSize -> 1/100, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}];
{M1[t], M2[t]} = {M1[t], M2[t]} /. sol1[[1]];

x = Sin[M1[t]]*Cos[M2[t]];
Plot[x, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
y = Sin[M1[t]]*Sin[M2[t]];
Plot[y, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]

z = Cos[M1[t]];
Plot[z, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]


ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> 1, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}]


imgtable = 
   Table[ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x, y, z}], {t, 0, tmax}, 
     PlotRange -> 1, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
     AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}], {tmax, 0.3, 100, 5}];~Monitor~tmax
ListAnimate[imgtable]


ListAnimate@
  Table[Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[0.1], 
     Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {x[t] \.t -> tmax, y[t] \.t -> tmax, 
         z[t] \.t -> tmax}}]]}, PlotRange -> 1, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}], {tmax, 0.3, 100, 
    5}]~Monitor~tmax (*The command needs to be changed*)
```

[image]

Comment: 1. `\.` is apparently wrong. 2. You're mixing up function and function relationship, think about what's wrong with the following: `f=Sin[t]; f[1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by @xzczd, the $t$ is already hardwired into your definition of $x$, so you can't use the expression `x[t]`.  The correct expression is just `x`, as in your `Plot[x, ...]` commands.  I think this is where you are trying to go, more or less

```
ListAnimate[Table[
  p = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x, y, z}], {t, 0, tmax}];
  g = Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[0.1],
     Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {x, y, z} /. t -> tmax}]]}];
  Show[p, g, PlotRange -> {1, 1, 1},
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z},
   PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"tmax =", tmax}], Blue]],
  {tmax, 0.3, 100, 5}]
 ]
```

[image]

I don't know how use the `Monitor` command with `ListAnimate`, so I just added a plot label.

Answer (score 9):

Another elegant solution is to simply take your full parameteric plot:

```
g = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x, y, z}], {t, 0, 100}, 
     PlotRange -> 1, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
     AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}];
```

Extract the points and then use [this sweet](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AnimatedArrow) `ResourceFunction` from Jon Mcloone:

```
pts = Cases[g[[1]], Line[pts_, rest___] :> pts, \[Infinity]][[1]];
b = BSplineCurve[Flatten[Partition[pts,2,1],1]];
Graphics3D[ResourceFunction["AnimatedArrow"][b, 
   "HeadCount" -> 20, "Period" -> 60, "HeadSize" -> .02]]
```

[image]